# How to detect a sign-out from Google Play achievements or leader-boards UI?

Tags: unity, google-play-services

I am making an android game in Unity (C#), in which I've used the [Google's official plugin for Google Play Services](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). My question is how to detect that a player has clicked on sign out button on Google's UI

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Unity you can check GPGS and Game Center login status via `Social.localUser.authenticated`. This will return a `bool` value that indicates either the user is logged in or not. `true` for logged in and `false` for logged out.

```
void PrintUserStatus()
{
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        print("Player is logged in");
    else
        print("Player is not logged in");
}
```

Comment: So, are you suggesting I put this inside my Update function and check every single frame ? I had this way in my mind,  but I was hoping some way like an event or something which rises as soon as the sign out is done.

Comment: In Update? not at all. Why don't you just check before any operation?

Comment: Actually I'm showing the current user name text on my main UI and I wanted to make it convert to user name (Local) when signed out, if I put this check before any operation then this text field will not update till user interacts, which is not much appreciated.

Comment: I can suggest an alternative solution, that is you can put a button for sign-out explicitly. So from there you can cover at least 50% of your problem

Comment: I have an explicit button already in my UI, but I was thinking of getting rid of this case. 
By the way, what will be the impact on performance if I put the Social.localUser.authenicated check in update method ? 
If it doesn't makes much of an effect I'm willing to go with approach.

Comment: By the way, I am also doing the same for video ads availability. No impact on device performance, although it is not recommended but you can give a try